# drf_spectacular schema generation threw exception when using ./manage.py makemigrations

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, pipenv

I get this error when I run `./manage.py makemigrations` and I don't know what is causing it (no relevant logs).

```
ERRORS:

?: (drf_spectacular.E001) Schema generation threw exception "relation "global_preferences" does not exist

LINE 1: ..."preferences"."preferences" FROM "global_prefer...
```

- Django 3.2.4
- DRF: 3.12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that when I run `pipenv install` to upgrade one of my package, it also upgraded `drf-spectacular` to v0.18.0 which is the cause of this [Github issue](https://github.com/tfranzel/drf-spectacular/issues/487#issuecomment-907159709).

Fixed it by pinning drf_spectacular to v0.17.3 until the issue is solved.